# Android: Detect status bar notification click

Tags: android, notifications

When my application fires a notification i want a method to be called after the user clicks the notification

This's how i create a notification :

```
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Date date = new Date();

    bundle.putString("name", "name");
    bundle.putString("body", "body");
    alarmIntent.putExtras(bundle);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 10000, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime()+5000, pendingIntent); // fire after 5 seconds of launch
```

So how to edit my code to achieve that .. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for notification

**for calling**

```
    notificationshow(this);
```

**method definition**

```
    notificationshow(Context c) {
        /*********** Create notification ***********/
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, act_run_ifclicknotifctn.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New Notification text title")
            .setContentText("New content text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            /*.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent)*/
            .build();

        NotificationManager NotiMgr = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotiMgr.notify(0, n);
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! this will launch act_run_ifclicknotifctn class, but is it possible to launch the main activity and call a method ? thanks

Comment: yes off course try to call your own class  myclass.class, if you wish to try method define boolean variable in notification and make then true
then call in resume method. check if a variable is true execute method if false then skip it